# Attempting to put arrows above equation with fractions - assume no or minimal packages installed

Tags: arrows, fractions, annotations

i am attempting to put arrows above and below fractions to help students with addition of fractions - only to be displayed on a web page

Something like this

[image: fractions 5/5 + 8/3 = 15/12 + 32/12]

This is the code for the fractions:

```
\LARGE {\frac{5}{4}+\frac{8}{3}}={\frac{15}{12}+\frac{32}{12}}
```

I cant work out how to do this - I am using a ready made environment - i can't call packages nor do I know what packages (if any) are installed. TKIZ is not installed however but amsmath might be.

Colours and curves are not necessary just a way to illustrate/annotate the fraction in a similar way.

Any help appreciated - thanks

Comment: With only the kernel and maybe `amsmath` this is not entirely impossible, but close to.

Comment: "*only to be displayed on a web page*": does this mean you are looking for something which works with MathJax or similar?

Comment: `\LARGE` does not take a `{...}` argument and can not be used in math mode, so it is hard to understand you fragment as you have not provided a test example.

Comment: TeX on its own can not do colour and can not draw curves, so there is no point showing coloured curved arrows and asking how to do them in basic tex (if you are using tex at all rather than say mathjax which is javascript) You need to say what back ends you may use, tikz, or pstricks or ...

Comment: "only to be displayed on a web page": does this mean you are looking for something which works with MathJax or similar? - I DONT KNOW - im happy to try stuff out and see if it works
__________
\LARGE does not take a {...} argument and can not be used in math mode, so it is hard to understand you fragment as you have not provided a test example. - IT WORKS AS IS on my webpages as long as i use some XML to define it as an equation

Comment: You need to say what back ends you may use, tikz, or pstricks or... - UNFORTUNATELY im using an XML based CMS and i have no control or access to the back end nor can i ask - its been set up beyond my contol.